# Shift UIImageView or similar Picture trough view

Tags: iphone, slider, image

i want to shift images trough the app, maybe like in the album or something similar, so  that i can watch one image after the next,...

how would you program that?

Such a kind of sliding would be nice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably use multiple `UIImageView`s in a `UIScrollView` with its [pagingEnabled](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScrollView/pagingEnabled) property set to YES. Each `UIImageView` should be the size of the `UIScrollView`'s bounds, and its [contentSize](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScrollView/contentSize)'s width should match the cumulated widths of all your `UIImageView`s.